# Ajax request succeeds but continues on to the target url regardless

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-masonry, masonry

I'm working on a page which contains various Youtube video thumbnails in divs which have links attached to each `<img>` and has Masonry on the container to control class switching to resize selected videos.

The idea is that the `div` is clicked on, which triggers masonry to change the CSS and also triggers an `.ajax()` request to django which returns the template for the selected video. (And will perform the opposite when you select it again to return the thumbnail template and reset to normal with Masonry).

As it stands I have two javascript functions, one triggering masonry on the div, and then another triggering the ajax request on the video link;

```
<script>
(function($) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var container = $('.masonry'), masonry;
        //masonry = new Masonry(container[0]);
        container.masonry('stamp', container.find('.stamp'));

        container.unbind('click').on('click', '.item', function() {
            var $this = $(this),
                this_link = $this.find('a'),
                $this_link = $(this_link),
                this_href = $this_link.attr('href'),
                video_id = $this.attr('data-video-id'),
                gigante = $this.hasClass('gigante'),
                selector = 'div#panel-area.video_grid div.masonry div.item.' + video_id;

            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                async: false,
                url: this_href,
                timeout: 5000,
                data: {'g': gigante},
                dataType: 'html',
                success : function(data) {
                    $(selector).html(data);
                    container.find('.item').removeClass('gigante');
                    $(this).toggleClass('gigante', !gigante);
                    container.masonry();
                    console.log('Selector: ' + selector + '\nSuccess');
                }
            })
            .done(function(msg){
                console.log('Done: ' + msg);
            })
            .fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus){
                console.log('Failed: ' + textStatus);
            });

        });
    });
})(jQuery);    </script>
```

And the HTML;

```
<div class="masonry js-masonry" data-masonry-options='{ "stamp": ".stamp", "isOriginLeft": false }'>
    <div class="mpus stamp">            
    </div>
    <div class="item video {{ object.id }}" data-video-id="{{ object.id }}">
        <a class="GetYoutubeVideo" href="{% url 'show_video' video_id=object.id %}">
            <i class="icon-play-circled play"></i>

            <span class="title">
                {{ object.get_title|slice:":20" }}...<br/>
                {{ object.date_created|date:"d/m/Y" }}
            </span>
            {{ object.get_img_tag }}
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm a javascript novice essentially so I'm sure this is a very basic issue. When I run this through chrome dev tools with `async` disabled I see the ajax request return the expected content, but then ultimately end up on the target page instead of loading the content in to `$(selector)` as expected.
When I enable `async` it just instantly fails. I've been reading docs for ages but don't feel like I'm getting anywhere. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To avoid the default click action, modify your click handler as follows:

```
.on('click', '.item', function(e) {
    var ...

    e.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({

        ...
    )}

    ...
})
```

Adding `e` to the click handler function means that the event details are available within the function - on the `e` object you run the `preventDefault()` method which prevents default actions from occuring - for instance, a hyperlink will no longer navigate to its target.

The event occurs in generally the following manner, though this is don't an in-depth summation:

A click event occurs on the `a` element.

The click event starts a search for an event handler. Should one not be found on the element that caused then the event will 'bubble' up the DOM tree, one level at a time until it either reaches the root DOM element and cannot go further, or a click handler is found.

At any point, should a click handler be found then the code in the click handler is executed. If the click handler sets `preventDefault()` on the event object, or returns `false` then no further action is taken.

If the click handler neither returns `false` nor sets `preventDefault()` then the original browser default action will be executed in addition to your own event handler.

Your code in full with modifications:

```
<script>
(function($) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var container = $('.masonry'), masonry;
        //masonry = new Masonry(container[0]);
        container.masonry('stamp', container.find('.stamp'));

        container.unbind('click').on('click', '.item', function(e) {
            var $this = $(this),
                this_link = $this.find('a'),
                $this_link = $(this_link),
                this_href = $this_link.attr('href'),
                video_id = $this.attr('data-video-id'),
                gigante = $this.hasClass('gigante'),
                selector = 'div#panel-area.video_grid div.masonry div.item.' + video_id;

            e.preventDefault();

            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                async: false,
                url: this_href,
                timeout: 5000,
                data: {'g': gigante},
                dataType: 'html',
                success : function(data) {
                    $(selector).html(data);
                    container.find('.item').removeClass('gigante');
                    $(this).toggleClass('gigante', !gigante);
                    container.masonry();
                    console.log('Selector: ' + selector + '\nSuccess');
                }
            })
            .done(function(msg){
                console.log('Done: ' + msg);
            })
            .fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus){
                console.log('Failed: ' + textStatus);
            });

        });
    });
})(jQuery);
</script>
```

Comment: Since `.item` is the wrapper around the link, the link click event will still get called first before the wrapping div, no? I'm never 100% sure on event bubbling or... (I forget the opposite name), but I thought events usually bubble up, not down.

Comment: @Flater Thats another thing I wasn't sure of - with event handlers, do they get triggered by the child elements & thus called twice. I was seeing my django view called twice by the ajax earlier.

Comment: Calling twice generally means you added the event listener twice. ...generally. Not always. Just common occurrence :)

Comment: @Flater yeah I think it stopped when I put the `unbind` in there.

Comment: Simple jsfiddle to demonstrate the bubbling scenario: http://jsfiddle.net/9Sd2g/1/

Answer (score 1):

Is there a point to setting a functioning `href` attribute on your `<a>` element if you don't want it to actually go to that URL directly?

Not trying to be clever, just asking if there is a specific reason for it.

Because the problem is that your `<a>` element is still performing its 'normal' duties, i.e. changing the page. I can see you retrieve that URL via jQuery at a later stage, but that shouldn't matter.

Change your used attribute to something that is NOT href:

```
<a class="GetYoutubeVideo" href="#" data-custom-url="{% url 'show_video' video_id=object.id %}">
```

And when you need to retrieve the value, just use that new attribute name:

```
this_href = $this_link.attr('data-custom-url')
```

Note that I'm not 100% sure if you *need* the href attribute for masonry. From what I can see from your code examples, it doesn't matter, as long as you're able to retrieve the value from *an attribute* (not specifically href).

By NOT using the href attribute, you're making sure your `<a>` element doesn't have an actual URL to refer to when it gets clicked.

Is this an acceptable solution/workaround?

Comment: Thats the solution I was trying to avoid. Before I was putting this together I was going for a non-js friendly site. But to be honest I don't know if that even matters.

Answer (score 1):

You could simply return false in your click event callback:

```
container.unbind('click').on('click', '.item', function() {
    ...
    #ajax
    ...
    return false;
});
```

I believe it's a more practical way of stopping the default action and preventing the event from bubbling up.

Comment: I believe I've seen that before but didn't understand it's use. Thanks.

Comment: `return: false` is equivalent to `e.preventDefault();` with `e.stopPropagation();`. I'd advise using the modern, fine grained approach to achieve what you intend.